# Error when converting json received from java servlet to array in PHP

Tags: json, php-5.2

In our web application there is a tomcat 5.5 server which runs a servlet that created a document, either PDF or Word, and then sends it back as json with this structure:

```
{
  "status": "OK", // or "ERROR" if an error occurred
  "format": "application/pdf", // or "application/msword" if a Word document was generated
  "document": [...] // document content
}
```

The `document` key is created by first exporting the document as a `byte[]` and then calling `toString()` on it.

The whole json is managed, in the servlet, by using [this library](http://json.org/java/), and [here](http://agews.com/example.json) you can see an example of response.

However, when the PHP script which calls the tomcat server receives the json string and runs it through `json_decode()`, it returns `NULL` as if the data was not valid json.

Did I make any obvious error in this algorithm I used? Or, more in general, **how do you properly transmit binary data using JSON?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself 'cause I found a solution to this problem even if I am unsure about what caused it in the first place.

Anyway, I found out that if I do a **base64 encoding** of the binary data before sending it as json, the json object gets properly parsed by the PHP script, and doing a **base64 decoding** successfully recreates the original document created by the servlet.